# Validation error

Tags: validation, html

this is the error: Line 29, Column 134: end tag for "img" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified

this is the line in question:

```
<div id="logo"><a href="http://sunnahspace.com/index.php"><img src="../img/logo.jpg" width="500" height="100" alt="SunnahSpace" ></a></div>
```

What am I missing, it looks just fine to me, and a google search of this issue shows that this is how it is supposed to look :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

end your img tag with a `/>`

```
<img src="../img/logo.jpg" width="500" height="100" alt="SunnahSpace" />
```